# (Node.JS Jimp) How do I center my text?

Tags: node.js, image

I have a 500px by 167px image and I want to add 2 lines of text but those need to be centered, how can I do it? I'm using node.js and the jimp package, the last line will always be changing length as in a different username!

```
Jimp.read("./imgs/background.png").then(function (image) {
        image.resize(500, Jimp.AUTO)
        .quality(100);
        image.write("./imgs/background-test.png");

      Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE).then(function (font) {

        //What do I do here? image.print(font, x, y, "Welcome Username", 7)

        image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, (err, buffer) => {
          image.write("./imgs/background-test.png");
        })
      });

      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? Maybe you can write so that others will benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I see this question has no answer yet, so for future reference I'll just answer this one.
This feature was added in version 285, but it was never really well-documented.

```js
image.print(font, pos.x, pos.y, {
    text: "Example test",
    alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
    alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER
}, pos.maxX, pos.maxY);
```

The `pos.maxX` and `.maxY` are sometimes needed so Jimp knows what the positions are to let the text be centered, *sometimes* it does this itself, but if it doesn't work then that's basically the first step in debugging.
If this doesn't work you could just use the old fashioned way, by getting the size of the image and bitmap, dividing those by two and defining those as the x and y (max) position(s).
Please give me feedback on this post, it's my first answer and I'd love to learn to write answers better.

Comment: hey mate, I just tried your answer and it gives an error that ```pos``` is not defined. any idea what that could be?

Comment: Well yeah, `pos`, `font`, etc are not yet defined (depending on your code), you could make an object so this works and doesn't look messy by doing something like `const pos = {"x": "position_coordinates", "y": "position_coordinates"}` (coordinates being measured in pixels). See [this PR on the repository](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/pull/285)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER` and  `Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE`

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');

Jimp.read("./imgs/background-test.png").then(function (image) {

    image.resize(500, Jimp.AUTO)
    .quality(100);
    image.write("./imgs/background-test.png");

  Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE).then(function (font) {

    image.print(font, 0, 0, {
      text: "Welcome Username",
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE
    }, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height);

    image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, (err, buffer) => {
      image.write("./imgs/background-test.png");
    })
  });

  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```